# Wordpress ContactForm7 not sending message to email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i'm using Wordpress 4.9.7 version , i installed ConatctForm7 plugin latest version.
When submitting the message , it is stored on ContactForm db exetsnion and not sent to email . Usually the form renders an error

> An error occurred while sending your message. Please try again
>   later.

But there is no error in the console .
Any idea how to solve that issue ?
thanks in advance

Comment: We can help if you share the error in php logs.

Answer (score 2):

We need more informations about the problem to solve it.

Basing on your question I assume, that maby you dot't have SMTP set up right.

> "WordPress uses mail function in PHP to send emails. Many shared
>   hosting providers do not have this function configured properly, or
>   they have disabled it entirely to avoid abuse. In either case, this
>   causes your WordPress emails to not be delivered."

here is tutorial for this :

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-smtp-server-to-send-wordpress-emails/

Answer (score 0):

The error message may appear in Red border or Orange Border and each type of error has different fixes, what's the border color you see in your site?

(step by step you can find here: https://wooexplorer.com/how-to-fix-contact-form-7-there-was-an-error-trying-to-send-your-message-please-try-again-later/)

**If red border message**

+Fix 1: Install sendmail on your server or ask for hosting provider to enable it for you

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

+Fix 2: Install SMTP plugin for wordpress like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/ (recommended)

**If orange border message**

This error happens when the reCAPTCHA module is not working properly on your site

I recommend to remove previous site key and secret key and install new ones.

To get new reCAPTCHA key, go to: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create